# Packing and unpacking a 32-bit number?

Tags: c#, bit

I have a project I'm working on where the file format stores the locations of various parts of the file in offsets. So, for example, the file will hold information about 8 different layers. There will be an offset in bytes to the data for each layer.

I'm having trouble calculating what that offset is as the way it is stored is confusing to me. I do have enough documentation to do it by hand but I don't know how to do it in code.

The docs say:

A packed offset is 32bits. The unpacked offset is also a 32 bit number to be used as a byte count. An offset is packed in memory as two words, or 4 bytes.

So, for example,

byte0 = `aaaaaaaa`
byte1 = `bbbbbbbb`
byte3 = `cccccccc`
byte4 = `ddddeeee`

The hi nibble of the low byte is appended to byte 0 and byte 2 as follows:

`dddd aaaaaaaa cccccccc`

Four 0 are added to the lo part (enforcing 16 byte chunkiness)

`dddd aaaaaaaa cccccccc 0000`

For completeness we specify that the high 8 bits of a 32 bit offset are 0.

**The final unpacked offset looks like this:**

`00000000 ddddaaaa aaaacccc cccc0000`

I can follow those instructions manually and come up with the correct numnber, but I don't know how to code that. I was copying another person's code who was working with the same filetype and they used:

`offset = (val1 << 12) + (val2 << 4) + (val3 <<4) + (val4 >> 4)`

val1, val2, val3, and val4 are just the 4 individual bytes. This worked fine for smaller numbers, but as soon as they got over a certain value, it no longer worked.

Can anyone help in getting this to work in C#?

Comment: Please add examples of the packed and unpacked values as hex strings.

Comment: Here are 2:  

Packed: 1A 00 AD F0
Unpacked: 15837904


Packed: 00 00 29 00
Unpacked: 656

Comment: `val1` is `byte0`? Just checking I understand how these are mapped.

Comment: Also, in your example, what happens to `byte1`? I don't see `bbbb` anywhere in your result!

Comment: Yes, in the other authors code, val1 = byte0. I noticed that bbbb isn't used anywhere. That confused me a bit, but it does work without it.  In the examples I've seen, byte1 is always 0 so that is probably why.

Comment: You may want to look at the `StructLayout` attribute with `LayoutKind.Explicit`. It will allow you to create a `struct` with members like `Full32`, `Word1`, `Word2`, and `Byte1` thru `Byte4`. It may simplify your code. Also decide if you want to use 0..3 or 1..4. Don't mix and match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your description, it looks like you need the following

```
offset = val1 << 12 | val3 << 4 | (val4 & 0xF0) << 16;
```

In this case, `val1` means `aaaaaaaa`, `val3` means `cccccccc` and `val4` means `dddddddd`. `val2` appears to be ignored.

Comment: This seems to provide the same answer as the original.

Comment: No `val4` is shifted 12 bits left rather than 4 to the right

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. What I meant was I thought the result was the same. But I just tried calculating it again and the original code would have parsed `0x1A` `0x00` `0xAD` `0xF0` to **109279** and yours gives **109264**. I don't understand it enough to know why there is a difference of 15, or maybe I'm calculating incorrectly, but either way, it is incorrect according to the specs above. It should parse out to **15837904** (`0xF1` `0xAA` `0xD0`).

Comment: Should be fixed now https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z4sW2z

Comment: Wow, you are amazing! Thank you so much. That is so much easier than the jumble of code I threw together!